# Java Swing/ JIDE renderer

Tags: java, swing, renderer, jide

I wanted to paint a render for stock ticks based on the previous value :

```
public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    Object o1 = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
    Object o2 = value;

}
```

Basically 
If  value in o1 < o2 then paint RED 
If  value in o1 > o2 then paint GREEN

Problem though is both o1 and o2 return the same value. How can I get the previous value contained in the renderer

Answer (score 0):

If the model and the table have the same value at this point, then the model has already been updated.  I don't think the table is a good place to expect to hold the "previous value"; I suggest instead trapping its change in the model and putting it somewhere reasonable there.  It won't be accessible by a call defined in the TableModel interface, but then this concept doesn't exist there so we shouldn't expect it to be.

Comment: Thanks Arcy... I agree with you; perhaps there could be a model developed which would cache in the previous updated values